# Unhandled win32 exception occurred in runMidlet.exe

Tags: java, java-me, mobile, mobile-phones

I am using Java ME Platform SDK 3 to start developing Java Mobile application. But I couldn't run a sample application in the emulator. Every time it compiles successfully and an error occurs in the emulator with this message "An Unhandled win32 exception occured in runMidlet.exe [xxxx]". I don't know what to do. I also try to use Netbeans IDE 6.7.1 but the same error is coming. can any body tell what could be the cause of the error and the solution.
I think it is related to the environment.(I am using Windows 2003 SP2 standard edition).

Answer (score 1):

Make sure that you have the required JDK installed (JDK 6) and then try installing the Java ME platform SDK. In addition check if you have Apple Quicktime installed